# Opencart show drop down error

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I'm wanting to have 'All' in the 'Show' drop down menu within the opencart website when viewing products in categories. I've been told it would take a lot of coding to do it in the correct manner so I've just tweaked the code as follows:

```
$this->data['limits'][] = array(
    'text'  => "All",
    'value' => 5000,
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=5000')
);
```

This seems to give an error in my error log as follows:

```
2013-02-07 11:22:12 - PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant All - assumed 'All' in /home/a6997914/public_html/catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 373
```

Do I need to define this 'All' or is my syntax incorrect? This method works as required as far as i know but delivering this error none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lines you shown are of product/category.php not seacrh.php

open your **catalog/controller/product/search.php** i am sure you are using ALL  there and not putting it in quotes like "ALL". use **"ALL"** and error should go away

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. That has solved the issue i'm still getting the following error:


`2013-02-09 2:22:52 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  path in /home/a6997914/public_html/catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 375` with the corresponding code: 

'$this->data['limits'][] = array(
    'text'  => "All",
    'value' => 5000,
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=5000')
   );'

Comment: @green4rrow are you sure this code is in search.php , anyways replace this code with following code `$this->data['limits'][] = array(
    'text'  => "All",
    'value' => 5000,
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&limit=5000')
   );`

Comment: Thanks @chetan i think i've copied across the code from the category.php file at some point without realising they aren't the same